# How to add a value in all NULL rows in a column in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql

In my database, there is a column expiry date that has expire date of users' accounts, but some users have NULL value in expiry date due to an earlier bug. So I want to change expiry date of all rows in that column, but do not want to make change to rows that has expiry date added already. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To test for `NULL` values, use the `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL`.

You did not provided more details about your table so I will give you generic example:

To **find** `NULL` values use `WHERE expiry IS NULL` aka

```
SELECT * FROM thetablename WHERE expiry IS NULL;
```

To **update** the `NULL` values use the same logic as above aka:

```
UPDATE thetablename SET expiry = '2022-01-01' WHERE expiry IS NULL;
```

> Always do the `SELECT` statement **with the same condition** in `WHERE` part to see what records will be impacted with the `UPDATE` statement.

To name at least two references about working with `NULL` values are [mariadb.com](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/null-values/) and [dev.mysql.com](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/working-with-null.html).